# Scaling SVG not working with Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, svg

I am having problems with SVG scaling in Internet explorer.

In Chrome it looks like this:

[image]

But in Internet Explorer it looks like this:

[image]

HTML:

```
<header id="topbar">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="logo">
      <a href="/">
        <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="64.2 25.7 158 49.9" style="width: 100%; enable-background:new 64.2 25.7 158 49.9;" xml:space="preserve"></svg>
      </a>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
#topbar {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
}

#topbar #wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
}

#topbar #wrapper #logo {
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#topbar #wrapper #logo svg {
  height: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
```

Is there a quick fix for this without doing something special?

Code: http://codepen.io/jakej/pen/vNRzGp

Comment: I've found height/width had some weird issues between browsers, I use the parent object as the actual size and just tell the svg to be 100% height/width of the container.  Works well in all browsers.

Comment: Explicit height seems to be the only approach to not get the default size : https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/.

Answer (score 0):

try this seems to work for me

```
#topbar #wrapper #logo a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background: blue;
}
```